# Fractional Laplacian for the product of two functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Considering the following definition for the fractional Laplacian
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{pointwisedef} (-\Delta)^{s}u(x) & : = & \mathrm{ \mbox{p. v}}   \quad a_{d,s} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))} {|x-y|^{d+2s}}dy \\
 \nonumber & : = &  a_{d,s}\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{\{y\in \mathbb{R}^d:\ \lvert x-y\rvert\} \ge \delta}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))} {|x-y|^{d+2s}}dy   
\end{eqnarray}

The Proposition 1.5 of [LOCAL ELLIPTIC REGULARITY FOR THE DIRICHLET FRACTIONAL
LAPLACIAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07560) by Umberto Biccari *et al.*, states that if $u, v$ be such that $(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(u)$ and $(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(v)$ exist and
\begin{eqnarray*}   
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}
 \frac{|(u(x)-u(y))(v(x)-v(y))|}{\vert x-y\vert^{d+2s}}dy < \infty. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Then $(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(uv)$ exist and is given by
\begin{eqnarray}\label{formula} 
(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(uv)=u(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(v)+v(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(u)-I_{s}(u,v)
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{eqnarray*}   
I_{s}(u,v)(x)=a_{s,d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}
 \frac{(u(x)-u(y))(v(x)-v(y))}{\vert x-y\vert^{d+2s}}dy. (1)
\end{eqnarray*}.
The above identity can be proved using $ab-cd=a(b-d)+b(a-c)-(a-c)(b-d)$. Now, regarding to (1)  , I have one question: Can the previous formula (1) be taken in a pointwise sense for $ u, v$ in a function space   different from the Schwartz space?

Comment: What do you mean by  " pointwise sense". For $u \in L^{2}$, $u(x)$ does not make sense.

Comment: In mi question ,  pointwise sense means  that \begin{eqnarray}
(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(uv)(x)=u(x)(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(v)(x)+v(x)(-\bigtriangleup)^{s}(u)(x)-I_{s}(u,v)(x)
\end{eqnarray}